# An expression, idiom, or phrase meaning "I lied" or "they are lying" or "to tell a lie", etc?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, shakespeare

Looking for an expression, idiom, or phrase that would indicate a lie is being told, or was told, etc.

I will not be using this phrase as part of a sentence, so I can't give an example. I just wanted a phrase that would convey this meaning. Some examples of what I am looking for include "to spin yarn" and "what a tangled web we weave". Thanks.

Comment: Sir Walter Scott: *Oh, what a tangled web we weave, when first we practice to deceive.*

Comment: So you're looking for an expression to refer to someone (or some thing) of questionable veracity, suggesting mendacity or prevarication?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with *I lied*? If you're not going to use it in a sentence, how *are* you gong to use it?

Comment: I am going to use it on it's own, as the sentence.

Comment: @peabody2 You mean a one-word sentence, consisting of this word? I'm finding it difficult to understand you. Can you let us have a bit more context?

Comment: Please note that this is not Any Language and Usage. This is specifically English Language and Usage. Asking for anything "written in another language" is off-topic. You can take such questions to our chat, for which you have sufficient reputation and where you'll find speakers of every language imaginable, including Latin and Greek.

Comment: Hi Peabody, and welcome to the website. We try to keep Stack Exchange thoughtful and avoid it devolving into a mere popularity polling website by implementing [subjectivity guidelines](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). We prefer it when we know the criteria which makes one option better than another, and one thing we specifically request for you to avoid is writing an answer alongside the question, while expecting more answers. Would you at least you tell us why the options you mentioned are inadequate, since you are including them in the body of the question as considerations?

Answer (score 1):

Some useful phrases:

- to lie through one's teeth = to lie
- Janus-faced = hypocritical, showing different people different selves
- Artful Dodger = a forger
- to spin a yarn = to tell a false tale
- Judas / quisling / Benedict Arnold / turncoat = a traitor

Comment: And I'm sure Samuel Clemens had 100 others in *Tom Sawyer* and *Huckleberry Finn*.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re looking for something that’s both playful and a reference to a classic piece of Italian literature you can use:

> **[Your nose is growing](https://americanliterature.com/english-language-idioms)**
> An expression used to confront someone for telling a lie, a reference to the Pinocchio puppet

This expression can go even further. If someone just told a lot of lies, you can say that their nose is so long it just hit you in the face. A good example of this can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=dpdzIWlEu_8C&pg=PT73&dq=%E2%80%9Cnose%20is%20growing%E2%80%9D&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUn8mX5tffAhWOm-AKHVFDArgQ6AEIUzAI#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9Cnose%20is%20growing%E2%80%9D&f=false).

Comment: Actually, it's a reference to a classic American cartoon, by Jiminy!